# How to make a fixture of entire django project for limited data in database?

Tags: django, django-models, dumpdata

I have a Django--1.3 project that contains 40+ applications in it I have found this to make limited data fixture:

```
manage.py makefixture --format=json --indent=4 proj.appname.modelname[1:1000] > test.json
```

But this makes a fixture for only 1 app at a time.
Is there any way that enables me to make fixtures just by running **one** command?
Please Help!

Comment: Hold on `makefixture`? There is no such command. Did you mean `dumpdata` command?

Comment: A 3rd party django app, `"django-test-utils" github.com/ericholscher/django-test-utils` contains a makefixture command implementation which is basically a smarter dumpdata.

Comment: @PauloBu dumpdata does not allow subsets of data from database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have `space` in between multiple app names:

```
manage.py makefixture --format=json --indent=4 proj.appname.modelname[1:1000] proj.another_appname.modelname[1:1000] > test.json
```

Help comes directly from the library, see [here](https://github.com/ericholscher/django-test-utils/blob/master/test_utils/management/commands/makefixture.py#L30).